# Powershell 5.1 outputting to a blank file

Tags: powershell, txt

I'm running a command to list directories, subdirectories, and a file count.  It works fine in powershell but I want it to output to a .txt file.  So far all it outputs is a blank file.

```
dir -recurse |  
  ?{ $_.PSIsContainer } |
    %{ Write-Host $_.FullName (dir $_.FullName |
       Measure-Object).Count }>list.txt
```

Comment: Remove `Write-Host`. Its only to display stuff to the console not for outputting to a text

Comment: [`Write-Host` is typically the wrong tool to use](http://www.jsnover.com/blog/2013/12/07/write-host-considered-harmful/), unless the intent is to write _to the display only_, bypassing the success output stream and with it the ability to send output to other commands, capture it in a variable, or redirect it to a file. To output a value, use it _by itself_; e.g., `$value` instead of `Write-Host $value` (or  use `Write-Output $value`). See the linked duplicate for more information.